# Couldn't able to remove double quotes from json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-mvc

I couldn't able to remove the double quotes from json string. Following is my code.

```
var values = {};
        $.each($('#regForm :input'), function(i, field) {
            if (field.name == "submit") {
                delete field.name;
            } else {
                values[field.name] = field.value; 
            }
        });
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(values);
        var global = JSON.parse(json_text);
        console.log(global);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : global,
            url : "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServices/register",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            },
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success"+data);
                console.log("Success:", data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("HI");
                   alert("Failed to cancel subscription! Message:" + textStatus /*+ jqXHR.errorThrown  + xhr.responseText*/);
                   alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                   alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                   alert("status: " + xhr.status);
                   alert("text status: " + textStatus);
                   alert("error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Here is my output when I see it in the firefox debugger:

```
"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"
```

I need the actual result:

```
{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

This is my server code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public RegisterResponse newAccount(@RequestBody Register registration) {
    String newAccountSql = "INSERT INTO register (email,password,username) VALUES (:email,:password,:username)";
    RegisterResponse regResponse = new RegisterResponse();
    regResponse.setResult(-1);
    // ServiceDataBean<AuthToken> retBean = new
    // ServiceDataBean<AuthToken>();
    try {
        System.out.println("register service calling.....");
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("email", registration.getEmail());
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] md5 = new byte[64];
        messageDigest.update(
                registration.getPassword().getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0,
                registration.getPassword().length());
        md5 = messageDigest.digest();
        namedParameters.addValue("password", convertedToHex(md5));
        namedParameters.addValue("username", registration.getUsername());
        GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        // TODO what to do with the updInt also check it's not -1
        int updInt = jdbcTemplate.update(newAccountSql, namedParameters,
                generatedKeyHolder);
        regResponse.setResult(0);
        System.out.println("from register");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        regResponse.setResult(001);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return regResponse;
}
```

Comment: When I try this json_text = {"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"} and global = {username:"hi", email:"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}.  The surrounding "" on json_text in the debugger are simply to signify that it is a string.

Comment: But why i am not able to post this data using ajax to spring rest service?? Rest service is working fine, I have tested it with poster pluging for firefox.

Comment: Are you confisung the JSON-string and the parsed object? What is the error from spring?

Comment: @phylax, it is going into error function. see my edited question. I have updated my question with Ajax call.

Comment: @user3496366 try data: json_text

Comment: @sWW, I tried it previously, not at all working. Now also I tried, not working. Again it is going into error function.

Comment: Is it being received correctly on the server with either method? i.e. is it binding to objects successfully?

Comment: yes, binding to objects is successful. If binding is not successful, then it would havn't work through poster(firefox plugin) also. But it is working through poster.

Comment: Sounds like an issue in your server code then if the data is getting there successfully.

Comment: Try removing the dataType : "JSON" from your ajax call.  dataType is the expected returned dataType.  It doesn't look like you are returning JSON so it will error.

Comment: this doesn't helped me. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
json_text= json_text.slice(1, json_text.length-1);
```

Comment: When I try this, `"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"`, but i need this `{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}`

Comment: I hope your text is `json_text= '"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"'`. This means there are double quote (") at beginning and end of your string. If there is NO double quote (") at beginning and end of the string you can simply use JSON.parse method to convert back to json object. Hope this helps and I am in same page with you.

Comment: Chandan, your comment saved me.

Answer (score 0):

See if writing your ajax request like this helps.  It removes the explicit dataType that I think could be causing you an issue and also removes the beforeSend function and replaces it with the built in contentType option (and removes the explicit return datatype).

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : global, //Or json_text, whichever worked.
    url : "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServices/register",
    contentType : "application/json",
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success"+data);
        console.log("Success:", data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("HI");
        alert("Failed to cancel subscription! Message:" + textStatus /*+ jqXHR.errorThrown  + xhr.responseText*/);
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
        alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
        alert("status: " + xhr.status);
        alert("text status: " + textStatus);
        alert("error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a need to replace any quotes, this is a perfectly formed JSON string, you just need to convert JSON string into object.This article perfectly explains the situation : [Link](http://blog.mycampusnotes.com/parse-json-string-over-ajax-using-csharp/)

Example :

```
success: function (data) {

        // assuming that everything is correct and there is no exception being thrown
        // output string {"d":"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        // now we need to remove the double quotes (as it will create problem and 
        // if double quotes aren't removed then this JSON string is useless)
        // The output string : {"d":"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        // The required string : {"d":{username:"hi",email:"hi@gmail.com",password:"123"}"}
        // For security reasons the d is added (indicating the return "data")
        // so actually we need to convert data.d into series of objects
        // Inbuilt function "JSON.Parse" will return streams of objects
        console.log(data);                     // output  : Object {d="{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        console.log(data.d);                   // output : {"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"} (accessing what's stored in "d")
        console.log(data.d[0]);                // output : {  (just accessing the first element of array of "strings")
        var content = JSON.parse(data.d);      // output : Object {username:"hi",email:"hi@gmail.com",password:"123"}" (correct)
        console.log(content.username);         // output : hi 
        var _name = content.username;
        alert(_name);                         // hi

}
```